# Swift - How to sort documents fetched from Firestore Database by date?

Tags: swift, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore

I have a tableViewController that gets loaded with documents fetched from Firestore Database. I would like to get them sorted by date and not ID, but I don't know where exactly to use sortby(). The documents already have a variable with the date, I am just not sure where I add the .sort(by: "date").

I already checked around, but most people have a very different code to populate their tableviews, and mine looks completely different.

Since I am new with Swift it took a lot of effort to get the tableViewController to work properly (mainly through online tutorials), but I don't fully understand it. This is the code:

This is an extension

```
class EncontradoService {
    let database = Firestore.firestore()

    func get(collectionID: String, handler: @escaping ([Encontrado]) -> Void) {
        database.collection("EncontradosFinal")
            .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, err in
                if let error = err {
                    print(error)
                    handler([])
                } else {
                    handler(Encontrado.build(from: querySnapshot?.documents ?? []))
                }
            }
    }
}
```

And this is in the tableViewController

```
    private var service: EncontradoService?
    
    private var allencontrados = [Encontrado]() {
           didSet {
               DispatchQueue.main.async {
                   self.encontrados = self.allencontrados
            }
        }
    }
       
    var encontrados = [Encontrado]() {
        didSet {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }



    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

     loadData()

     }

    func loadData() {
          service = EncontradoService()
        service?.get(collectionID: "EncontradosFinal") { encontrados in
              self.allencontrados = encontrados
          }
        
        
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: The documentation on [sorting data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#swift) has pretty good example. If you can't get those to work, can you show what you tried with the API mentioned there, and what error you got?

Comment: Hi!, thanks for the comment. I have seen the examples before, but since I am using "service?.get(collectionID:" to get the data, it doesn't work for me. I mean there is no place for the sortby function. @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: You made that service yourself though. Consider passing a `Query` instead of the collection name, or an optional sort order to it instead.